# How do you display the array responses back to the user after establishing & validating their input? c++

Tags: c++

newer at this but im drawing a blank on how to simply display the user's responses back. any feedback is so appreciated!

currently what i have:

```
int array[5] = {};

    int i;
    int numbers;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {       
        std::cout << "Please enter a number: ";
        std::cin >> numbers;
            if (std::cin.fail())
            {
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');

            }

    }
    std::cout << "You entered: " << array[numbers] << std::endl;
```

Comment: `array[i] = numbers;` in the loop.  Then loop over the array to output the array values.

Comment: Perhaps you should write the variable `numbers` into the correct indexes of `array`? Like `array[i] = numbers`. Then use another loop to display each element of the array.

Comment: Something like `array[i] = numbers;` inside the loop?

Comment: I guess the issue is that `i` should only be incremented if the input is valid. Maybe you want a do {} while() loop instead of a for loop although either will work.

Comment: @Eljay a little newer. could you give me a visual example. im sorry for being such a pain

Comment: One `int` variable cannot store many *numbers*. It can store just one. Call it a `number`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you really want is the printing of the array that is filled by the user inputs if i am not wrong.I want to bring to your consideration that the thing you have done is not even storing the inputs to the array.
On going further assuming that you have the array concept. Now the problem you are facing is the access to that.
Arrays have 2 things:

- Size : is the actual size in this case 5
- Indexes: are the places as 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 these are called indexes like in the array if you want to access the first element you will go for the index 0.
  [visual explanation of this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agEDC.png).

Now to access the first element you use the 0 index, thus for this we use subscript operator [], you will say array[0], this will access the first element that is on index 0.
[Check more description from here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-in-c-cpp/#:%7E:text=An%20array%20in%20C%2FC%2B%2B,etc%20of%20any%20particular%20type.)

where as your code is concerned when you have taken input now you should save this in array as

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{       
        std::cout << "Please enter a number: ";
        std::cin >> numbers;
            if (std::cin.fail())
            {
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');

            }
            
            array[i] = numbers; //now this will assign enter to array as i will be 0 then to 0 index first element, 1 index second element and so on

}
```

After this printing of the array elements can also be done similarly. Then statement you have written has problems as

```
 std::cout << "You entered: " << array[numbers] << std::endl;
```

The problem here is that **array[numbers]** here number can be any entered by the user last time if he enters 8 then array[8] it will give you an error as out of bound the array was declared. Remember arrays are of fixed size. Similarly if 5 then also error as although size is 5 but have 4 index to access 5 element. Thus other problem is that you will only display a single number by it if in range was entered if as 0 then only first element. The solution to this can be as:

```
std::cout << "You entered elements as : " << std::endl;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{      
       //this will now print all five elements as i will start from 0 and will end at 4 and all indexes will be displayed;
       std::cout << "Element " << i+1 <<" : " << array[i] << std::endl;
}
```

That's all and you are done :)

Comment: adding the suggestions you so nicely helped me with still gives me this: 

Please enter a number: 1
Please enter a number: 2
Please enter a number: 3
Please enter a number: 4
Please enter a number: 5
You entered: -858993460

i would like answers entered in the 5 slots to displayed like:
you entered: 12345

Answer (score 0):

This is output requirement. you may just go with this for the last loop of printing

```
std::cout << "You entered elements as : ";

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{      
       //this will now print all five elements as i will start from 0 and will end at 4 and all indexes will be displayed;
       std::cout << array[i];
} 

 std::cout<<std::endl;
```

Comment: @thatonedesertblonde refer to this for the thing you asked in comment